# GeoMesa Spark can't use geohash

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, geohashing, geomesa

I am using GeoMesa Spark on a Databricks cluster referring to this sample notebook: [GeoMesa - NYC Taxis](https://databricks.com/notebooks/GeoMesa-NYC-Taxis.html). I had no problem importing and using UDF functions such as `st_makePoint` and `st_intersects`. However, when I try to use `st_geoHash` to create a column of geohash of the points, I got this error:

`NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.locationtech.geomesa.spark.jts.util.GeoHash$`.

The cluster has `geomesa-spark-jts_2.11:3.2.1` and `scala-logging_2.11:3.8.0` installed, which are the two given by the [notebook](https://databricks.com/notebooks/GeoMesa-NYC-Taxis.html) (but with a different version of GeoMesa, 2.3.2 in the notebook while 3.2.1 on my cluster). I am new to GeoMesa and Databricks platform. I wonder if I missed some dependencies for the Geohash class to work.

Comment: Did you install the dependencies as a Maven package?

Comment: Also, you could try a bundled jar like the geomesa-gt-spark-runtime_2.11 one?

Comment: @GeoMesaJim Thank you for your suggestion, but how do I install that? I tried install it directly from Maven, but it gave me an error saying: `RuntimeException: unresolved dependency: org.geotools:gt-process-feature:23.3: not found`. Then I tried to find this geotools package but could not find the one with the exact name. I am curious how do I set up dependencies in general on a cluster. I am not quite familiar with Linux or virtual environment.

Comment: @EmilioLahr-Vivaz What do you mean? I searched and installed the packages from the Maven Libraries like AbhishekKhandave-MT pointed out below.

Comment: You can install the geomesa-gt-spark-runtime_2.11 jar by downloading it from maven, then installing it with the "upload" option. that jar is a shaded jar that contains all the required dependencies.

Comment: Re: installing the original jar, yes, I was wondering if you installed it as a Maven package (which should pull the transitive dependencies) or just as an uploaded jar. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @EmilioLahr-Vivaz Installing geomesa-gt-spark-runtime_2.11 from an uploaded jar worked. Thank you so much. But I still could not use geohash.

Comment: You could try removing the scala-logging dependency, if you haven't already. We've had to do things like this to work around DataBricks classpath, possibly their environment has changed and created a new conflict: https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/geomesa-3.3.0/geomesa-gt/geomesa-gt-spark-runtime/pom.xml#L143-L147

Comment: @EmilioLahr-Vivaz I changed to geomesa-gt-spark-runtime_2.12 and now it works. I did not pay attention to the cluster's Scala version. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated 18 OCT) I am one of the original contributors to this notebook along with Derek Yeager who was the primary author. Complex frameworks like geomesa may require more special attention as our UI maven support on clusters is built for streamlined library installs, more [here](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/cluster-libraries.html#cluster-installed-library). The notebook was originally built for  Spark 2.4 (DBR 6.x) on a fat jar of geomesa that we generated back at that time (late 2019). That jar shaded some dependency conflicts with DBR. Instead of the fat jar, you could use [Databricks Container Services](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/custom-containers.html) which can be useful for deploying more complex frameworks over our clusters. Should mention that DBR 7+ / Spark 3+ is Scala 2.12 only, so you wouldn't expect Scala 2.11 to work on those runtimes.

CCRi (backers of geomesa) has generated Databricks friendly build. A shaded fat jar for GeoMesa (current version is 3.3.0) is available at the maven coordinates `org.locationtech.geomesa:geomesa-gt-spark-runtime_2.12:3.3.0` which is for spark runtimes (such as Databricks)​.​ ​S​ince it is shaded, users can add maven exclusions to get it to cleanly install which would be "`jline:*,org.geotools:*`" added in Databricks library UI without quotes​. I have been able to execute the notebook you referenced (with some small changes) on DBR 9.1 LTS (for Spark 3.1).

1. One change from the initial notebook is you no longer need to specially add `com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.11:3.8.0`
2. Another is that you cannot change the spark configs inside the session, so you would minimally comment out (and could potentially add to cluster config if want):

```
// spark.conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
// spark.conf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", classOf[GeoMesaSparkKryoRegistrator].getName) 
// spark.conf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max","500m")
```

3. Comment out the skew hint and let Spark 3.x AQE handle:

```
//short circuit on geohash and apply geospatial predicate when necessary

val joined = trips.as("L")
    // - let AQE handle skew
    //.hint("skew", "pickup_geohash_25", pickup_skews).as("L")
    .join(
      neighborhoodsDF.as("R"),
      ( $"L.pickup_geohash_25" === $"R.geohash" ) && 
      ( st_contains($"R.polygon", $"L.pickupPoint") )
    )
    .drop("geohashes")
    .drop("geohash")
    .drop("polygon")
```

I have access to all the data from within the Databricks environment in which we produced the notebook, so I am assuming you are somehow reconstituting the data on your side if you are attempting to execute your copy the notebook.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. I looked into your notebook because I was working on a large GPS points dataset from INRIX and had performance issues on spatial join. So I tried to implement Geohash method. Now the speed does improve a lot. Although I have used Spark/PySpark for a while, I am pretty new to Geomesa, and know few about configuration and optimization of the Spark environment (especially on a virtual environment). Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install same version of `geomesa-spark-jts_2.11` as given in this [notebook.](https://databricks.com/notebooks/GeoMesa-NYC-Taxis.html)

To install `geomesa-spark-jts_2.11:2.3.2` follow below steps:

**Step1:** Click on install library.

**Step2:** Select Maven, Search and install `geomesa-spark-jts_2.11:2.3.2`.

**Step3:** You can also download jar file and upload it to Library Source.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Although the GeoMesa jars are hosted on Maven central, the geotools jars are hosted on a custom repository (https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release). I'm not sure if you can use multiple repositories when adding a Maven package in Databricks.